# Groupby or aggregate on big df

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, aggregate

I'm not understanding how to groupby on a large df in R.

Columns 0-12 are identifiers, unique, and I would like to leave them as is

I've tried a number of variations of this

```
aggregate(cbind(names(preferences[-c(0, 12)])) ~ 
            cbind(names(preferences[c(0, 12)])), data=preferences, FUN=sum)
```

I'm getting

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = cbind(names(preferences[-c(0, 12)])) ~  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'cbind(names(preferences[c(0, 12)]))')
```

```
a  b     c   d   e
1  f(1)  11  2   15
1  f(1)  12  2   15
2  f(2)  13  4   3
2  f(2)  14  6   4
3  f(3)  15  5   6

a  b     c   d   e
1  f(1)  23  4   30
2  f(2)  27  10  7
3  f(3)  15  5   6
```

Python equivalent `df[11:624].groupby(by=col11)`

df is 48GB so speed matters (python crashes due to a lack of memory(250GB))

After receiving an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71259932/6574038) I went and looked at some [benchmarks](https://h2oai.github.io/db-benchmark/) and this is fast as heck!!!!

Comment: Are you able to provide a re-producible example (of a smaller dataset) and the expected result? I am unclear as to what you are trying to achieve

Comment: if `df[11:624]` in python does not throw an error, then the column names are just the sequence 11:624, yet you are grouping by `col11`. What exactly is `col11`?

Comment: Is it the case you want to group by the first 12 columns, and get the sum for all other columns for each of these groups? Given the large size, the `data.table` or `collapse` packages will likely be much more efficient than base R.

Comment: @SweepyDodo  That has been updated

Comment: @JonSpring an implementation will get accepted!!!

Comment: @tjaqu787 referring to your comment on `data.table`'s benchmark. Yes, it was built from the ground up to be fast (and scalable). It is indispensable at my work. I feel this will be truer than ever given the forever growing data. Bear in mind its syntax `x[i,j,by]`. [Here](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/reference/data.table.html) is a quick guide. Lastly, tag future questions with `data.table`. Glad could help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)

x <- names(df)[13:ncol(df)]

y <- names(df)[1:12]

df_2 <- df[, lapply(.SD, \(i) sum(i)), .SDcols=x, by=y]
```

Though be aware of indexing in R vs Python. R starts counting from 1 (whereas Python has zero indexing)